# Showing List<object> in listView

Tags: android, database, listview, generics

Sorry for my bad english.this is part of a data base that show in a listview names of clients of a store.I have the following code:

```
private void updateCustomerList(){
        mdatabase=new MiDataBase(mcontext);
        customerList=new ArrayList<Customer>();
        customerList=mdatabase.getallCustomer();//this call getallCustumer
        customerListStr=new ArrayList<String>();
        mlistView=getListView();
        if(customerList==null||customerList.size()<=0){
            customerListStr.add("NO SE HAN AÑADIDO CLIENTES");
            unregisterForContextMenu(mlistView);
        }else{
            Customer item=new Customer();
            for(int i=0;i<customerList.size();i++){
                item=customerList.get(i);
                customerListStr.add(item.getName());
            }
            registerForContextMenu(mlistView);
        }
        MyArrayAdapter marrayAdapter=new MyArrayAdapter(mcontext,customerListStr);
        mlistView.setAdapter(marrayAdapter);
    }
```

Method getallCustomer is:

```
public List<Customer>getallCustomer(){

    ArrayList<String>marrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Customer> mcustomerList=new ArrayList<Customer>();
    marrayList.add(Customer.camposCust.name.toString());
    Customer mcustumer=new Customer();
    String[]marrayColumn=marrayList.toArray(new String[marrayList.size()]);
    Cursor mcursor;
    openDB();
    mcursor=database.query(nombreT,marrayColumn,null,null,null,null,null);
    mcursor.moveToFirst();
    int mindex=mcursor.getColumnIndex(Customer.camposCust.name.toString());
    while(mcursor.isAfterLast()==false){
        mcustumer.setName(mcursor.getString(mindex));
        mcustomerList.add(mcustumer);
        mcursor.moveToNext();
    }
    mcursor.close();
    closeDB();
    return mcustomerList;
}
```

and the Customer class is:

```
public class Customer
{
    private String city;
    private String address;
    private String cel;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private int customerID;

    public enum camposCust{
        city,
        address,
        cel,
        email,
        name,
        _customerID
    }
    public void setCity(String city)
    {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCity()
    {
        return city;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setCel(String cel)
    {
        this.cel = cel;
    }

    public String getCel()
    {
        return cel;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setCustomerID(int customerID)
    {
        this.customerID = customerID;
    }

    public int getCustomerID()
    {
        return customerID;
    }
}
```

the problem is when I introduce two or more items, in the listview just show the last item introduced more than once,like the following picture:for example I introduced three items:Juan, Peter and Joseph. Juan and Peter doesn't show

[image]

I hope you understand and someone can helpe please. I will appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String>marrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Customer> mcustomerList=new ArrayList<Customer>();
    marrayList.add(Customer.camposCust.name.toString());
    // Customer mcustumer=new Customer();
    String[]marrayColumn=marrayList.toArray(new String[marrayList.size()]);
    Cursor mcursor;
    openDB();
    mcursor=database.query(nombreT,marrayColumn,null,null,null,null,null);
    mcursor.moveToFirst();
    int mindex=mcursor.getColumnIndex(Customer.camposCust.name.toString());
    while(mcursor.isAfterLast()==false){
     Customer mcustumer=new Customer();
        mcustumer.setName(mcursor.getString(mindex));
        mcustomerList.add(mcustumer);
        mcursor.moveToNext();
    }
    mcursor.close();
    closeDB();
    return mcustomerList;
}



create the customer inside loop.
```